# Where does this (Django) CustomUser field come from?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-custom-user

My searches only turned up tips on how to add `fields` or `add_fieldsets` in `admin.py` when using Django's CustomUser. I need to find out where a field named `admin` comes from when the model form is rendered in the class-based `CreateView`. There is no error with the code, but the template automatically adds an `admin` choice field on top of the page-the drop-down choices are users (all 3 types) already created. But I want to create a new `staff` user. So how do I tell Django to leave the `admin` field out (at least until a user is saved)?

```
# models.py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_data = ((1, "HOD"), (2, "Staff"), (3, "Student"))
    user_type = models.CharField(default=1, choices=user_type_data, max_length=10)

class Staff(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()
    objects = models.Manager()


# forms.py
class StaffForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Staff
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Staff
        fields = '__all__'

# views.py
class StaffCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Staff
    form_class = StaffForm
    context_object_name = 'staff'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('staff_list')


# staff_form.html
<form method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form specifies `fields = '__all__'`, which includes `Staff.admin` one-to-one field. The `StaffForm.first_name` and `StaffForm.last_name` override the formfield for those model fields, but aren't strictly why those fields are present on the form.

If you want to remove the `admin` field from `StaffForm` you should replace `fields = '__all__'` with `fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']` or `exclude = ['admin']`.

You can read more on [the Django docs for selecting model form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use).

Comment: Tried both of your suggestions, but got error: `NOT NULL constraint failed: app_staff.admin_id`. I understand that the `admin_id` gets generated once the `staff` object is created, what I have a hard time understanding is how to use and access the  `admin` in the `staff` model. In the DetailView, a `staff` has 2 ID's: `staff.id` and `staff.admin_id`--they are different. I did read Django docs, but got stuck due to limited knowledge base.

Comment: I should have seen that coming. While you can render the form without the field you will need to provide the `admin` field to your `Staff` model some other way. `admin_id` is the field used to represent the value of `admin` in the database.